# Creating Structured Documents (books) in Wordpress?

Tags: custom-field

I've been trying to rebuild one of my websites story archives in Drupal. I have a personal website I wouldn't mind putting in Wordpress, but I want an easy way to create structured documents. That is to say I wanr a parent Story page, that has links and hierarchy for the Chapters under it. Is this doable in Wordpress?

Comment: Yes, you could do this in WordPress. Probably have to do some customization to it or find a theme that does it for you, vanilla WordPress out of the box won't be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/anthologize/
Didnt use it myself but time ago I created something similar but using pages and then using a plugin to reorder them then you can create links in the sidebar to simulate an index.. very raw.. but works

Comment: FOund that one and giving it a test as I go. Also turned on jetpack and portfolios so we'll see how it looks when I'm done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this out of the box with Pages, which are hierarchical.

You could also create a custom post type (Story), make it hierarchical and be able to continually manage and extend it as the needs of your site and story change.

If you want to go the extra mile, add Category and Tag taxonomies for even more sorting capabilities.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types and
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: This is actually something I've been looking for since I had to rebuild my last story archive site and decided to use Drupal since I couldn't get what I needed with Wordpress on it. While I still think that is the case for that one, I'm pretty sure I can make this work for me in my personal sites setup. Thanks, I'll see what I can do with this.